# A javascript function isn't taken into account in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have some javacript functions that I have defined in one scope variable like this:

```
$scope.salma = {
    selectedRestaurants: accounts.selectedRestaurants,
    findAllAccountsByRestaurant: function(restaurant) {
        angular.forEach(accounts.AllRestaurantAccounts, function(CurrentAllrestaurantAccount) {
            if(CurrentAllrestaurantAccount.nameRestaurant === restaurant) {
                accounts.currentRestaurantNumberAllAccount = CurrentAllrestaurantAccount.accountNumber;
            }
        });

        return accounts.currentRestaurantNumberAllAccount;
    },

    findAccountsOptInMAIL: function(restaurant) {
        angular.forEach(accounts.AllOptInMAILRestaurantAccounts , function(CurrentAllrestaurantAccountOptInMAIL) {
            if(CurrentAllrestaurantAccountOptInMAIL.nameRestaurant === restaurant) {
                accounts.currentRestaurantNumberOptInMAIL = CurrentAllrestaurantAccountOptInMAIL.accountNumber;
            }
        });

        return accounts.currentRestaurantNumberOptInMAIL;
    }
};
```

I make a call to these function in my html like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="restaurant in salma.selectedRestaurants">
        <td>{{ restaurant }}</td>
        <td>{{ salma.findAllAccountsByRestaurant(restaurant) }}</td>
        <td>{{ salma.findAccountsOptInMAIL(restaurant) }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The first function take effect in the html but the second one doesn't take effect and I don't know why.Have you any suggestions, please?

Comment: Are you sure the function is returning the right result? if there's no match in `AllOptInMAILRestaurantAccounts`, your function will probably return undefined. (Hard to tell exactly, without seeing who else modifies `accounts`)

Comment: Have you stepped into that second function? Maybe `accounts.currentRestaurantNumberOptInMAIL` is being returned, it's just undefined. EDIT: I swear doldt's comment was not visible when I made this one! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response.It was the problem.I have another small issue:    This is the code:         accounts.restaurants= $scope.$parent.filters.selection;
                        accounts.selectedRestaurants= [];
 accounts.getRestaurantsNames = function () {
     angular.forEach(accounts.restaurants, function (currentRestaurant) {
       accounts.selectedRestaurants.push(currentRestaurant.name);
     })
   }   accounts.getRestaurantsNames();The accounts.selectedRestaurants variable isn't filled and I don't know why